# Palindrome Checker in JavaScript - don't know how to debug

Tags: javascript, regex, debugging, palindrome

I want to build a palindrome checker in javascript. All non-letter characters should be removed, so that a phrase like "A man, a plan, a canal. Panama" can also be a palindrome.

```js
function reverse(str) {
  return str.split("").reverse().join("");
}


function palindrome(str) {
  str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/,"").toLowerCase();
  if(str == reverse(str)) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Now, where is the mistake in the above lines?

The code works on some examples. But for instance "A man, a plan, a canal. Panama" and "never odd or even" return false, meaning somewhere has to be a mistake.

Comment: Can you provide some examples: what does work? What doesn't work? Does "abba" return `true` or not? .. Give as much information as possible :)

Comment: "where is the mistake?" does it not work? any errors?

Comment: From the examples I've run it works.

Comment: `String.replace()` replaces only one match unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: [test-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/memnekky/) seems to be working here as well.

Comment: That said, learning some basic debugging skills wouldn't hurt; e.g. `console.log(str)` right after the replacement would have immediately told you where the problem is.

Comment: Should be `str = str.replace(/[^a-z]+/ig, '').toLowerCase();`

Comment: To people who say it works: try it with the "A man, a plan..." test string.

Comment: Avoid writing `if (a == b) return true else return false` when you can write `return a == b;`

Comment: Did you debug your program? For example, put a breakpoint at the line `if (str == reverse(str))`, and examine `str` and `reverse(str)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide the [global match flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global) to your regex:

```
/[^a-zA-Z]+/g
            ^
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common misconception. The replace() method does not replace all instances of what you want to replace in a string. It simply replaces the first instance and stops. If you refactor your regEx like this:

```
function reverse(str) {
  return str.split("").reverse().join("");
}


function palindrome(str) {
    var find = "[^a-zA-Z]";
    var regEx = new RegExp(find, 'g');
  str = str.replace(regEx,"").toLowerCase();
  if(str == reverse(str)) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

That will work.

Answer (score 1):

From the example given, it seems to me that the code doesn't work for spaces in between the letters. (There may be other scenarios as well)

I have changed this line :

```
str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/,"").toLowerCase();
```

To this :

```
str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g,"");
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line:

```
str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/,"").toLowerCase();
```

to this:

```
str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0123456789]+/g,"");
```

Answer (score -1):

This regex should work for your code.

`/[^1-9a-zA-Z]+/g`